Blye Yeti not showing up in Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
I've just gotten a Blue Yeti microphone, which worked fine under Windows.
I'm not running it on an Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS... and it lights up fine with the red light, and when I click mute, it blinks and react fine as well.. but the device isn't visible as an input device. Tried disconnecting, reconnecting etc..
No Linux expert, so I have no idea how to fix this. Anyone know?

Your question says you are not running it on Ubuntu. I think there might be an error in the question.
